# Connecting to AES encrypted wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless

Trying to connect my laptop to my university network which uses WPA2 Enterprise and AES encryption, however the wireless connection doesn't have AES encryption option. I can't get it connected at all, there's a guide to connect in Windows which is listed here : http://studentprojects.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/73/ . Could someone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

WPA2 uses AES by default. You aren't seeing the option, but its there. Looking at that guide, I bet your issue is more about the username/password login or this line "3) Verify that authentication method is set to Microsoft: Protected EAP (PEAP)."

Do you  have a really old laptop that doesn't support WPA2?
Logs or error messages would be helpful too. 
Do you have a password at all?

This might help too http://www.lug.wsu.edu/wireless/peap/ubuntu
But I'm not positive this is your issue.

Comment: It is set to Microsft: Protected EAP (PEAP) and I'm sure the username and password is correct. On my windows boot it connects without errors so I know my laptop supports WPA2.